# Feed Variables in Tensorflow Efficiently

Tags: tensorflow

I need to have a dictionary fed to a set of variables in Tensorflow and actually change their values. I tried: sess.run([], feed_dict=feed_dict), the run result was executed using the feed_dict, but the variable values are not updated. To update the values, I also tried doing "load" on each variable. That works, but is extremely inefficient. Loading a ~20 variables of 20M data takes 10s. I need it to be within 1s. (Feeding it only takes ~100ms) Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Below is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

variables = []
for i in range(100):
    variables.append(tf.Variable(np.random.rand(100, 100)))

sess = tf.Session()

feed_dict = dict()
for var in variables:
    feed_dict[var] = np.ones((100, 100))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())



# this is fast but do not actaully load variables (~ 14ms)
sess.run(variables, feed_dict=feed_dict)

# this loads, but is extremely slow (~8s)
data = np.ones((100, 100))
for var in variables:
    var.load(data, sess)
```

Comment: Please show code in the form of a mcve. Not sure what you mean

Comment: Added an example. Thanks:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
sess.run(variables, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

does not update the values of the variables, it simply runs the tensor as though the variables were placeholders fed the values from feed_dict. If you want to change the values of variables you can use tf.assign:

```
data = np.ones((100, 100))
assg = [tf.assign(var, data) for var in variables]
sess.run(assg)
print(sess.run(variables)) # arrays of 1s
```